# How to print message when text not found with fileinput? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How do I return a message, whether through the terminal or ctx.send (on discord), when a text I am trying to edit with fileinput does not exist?

Essentially I am trying to make sure that this job (or file in this case) has been claimed by this user by checking if their ID matches with the text that is after "Pilot:", if not, they can't un-claim it and that causes the script to return a message to the user via ctx.send().

**I have tried...**

```
@bot.command() #Work in progress
async def unclaim(ctx, *, message=None):

    author = ctx.author.id
    author = '<@'+str(author)+'>'
    mylines = []

    with fileinput.input(cwd+'/jobs/'+message+'.txt', inplace=True) as f:
        for line in f:
            mylines.append(line)
            pilot = mylines[2]
            pilot = pilot.split(':')[1]
            if author != pilot:
                await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, you have not claimed this job.')
            else:
                print(line.replace('<@'+str(author)+'>', 'no one'), end='')
```

**Error Received**
*Updated with new error*
I noticed that running `unclaim` results in the file being accessed to be emptied. Not sure why.

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\dispatch_bot\bot.py", line 98, in unclaim
    pilot = mylines[2]
IndexError: list index out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Projects\dispatch_bot\bot.py", line 45, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 855, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: list index out of range
```

**Text file being accessed...**

```
Leg: KBYS>KSQL
Max Weight/Pax: 0/12
Pilot: no one
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) Remove `pilot = mylines[2]` and subsequent lines from inside the `for` loop. `for line in f: mylines.append(line)` can be replaced with `mylines = f.readlines()`.

Comment: I fixed the error and forgot to update the post, it was because I had an empty file in the folder it was parsing through making the list I was trying to access out of reach. I still need help figuring out my problem though. I also don’t get why people are so eager to downvote. Is my questions not valid? I am not too familiar with fileinput and looking over their documentation, I can’t seem to find the information I need.

Comment: And thank you for the advice, I will do that.

Comment: Scratch the `readlines()` bit: I didn't notice you were using `fileinput` instead of just regular old `open()`. Can you clarify what the state of the problem is now? What is the latest code you've tried and what is the error it gives?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I updated the post with the code I have tried and the new error. Question - removing ```pilot = mylines[2]``` shouldn't affect the code correct? That is more of an organizational type of correction?

Also, when I run unclaim it erases everything in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Code that fixed the issue.

```
@bot.command() #Work in progress
async def unclaim(ctx, *, message=None):

    author = ctx.author.id
    author = ' <@'+str(author)+'>' #need to remove space from front of <@ in text file
    author_is_pilot = False
    mylines = []

    with open(cwd+'/jobs/'+message+'.txt', 'r+') as f:
        for line in f:
            mylines.append(line)
        pilot = mylines[2]
        pilot = pilot.split(':')[1]

    if author == pilot:
        author_is_pilot = True
        with fileinput.input(cwd+'/jobs/'+message+'.txt', inplace=True) as f:
            for line in f:
                print(line.replace(author, ' no one'), end='')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, you have not claimed this job.')
```

Two issues with my code in the beginning.

1. (As suggest by Pranav) the `pilot=mylines[2]` and the subsequent line in the for loop made the list I was trying to access out of range.
2. The variable `author` did not take the space into account when a job was claimed. (i.e Pilot = <@238472959>
   ^

I do think the code I wrote originally can also be used, but might need to fix the issues listed above. Will test another day after some sleep. I apologize if this question was not necessary, I was under the impression that because I was using fileinput that I was limit on what I could do within `with`.